# Serialize/Access a ExtensionDataObject

Tags: c#, .net

Currently i have a sample code which has a class which looks like the following:

```
public partial class PositionData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
        private string BCRSideField;
        private string ConveyorField;
        private string LineField;
        private string OriginField;
        private string SubConveyorField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public string BCRSide
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BCRSideField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BCRSideField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public string Conveyor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ConveyorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ConveyorField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public string Line
        {
            get
            {
                return this.LineField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.LineField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Origin
        {
            get
            {
                return this.OriginField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.OriginField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public string SubConveyor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.SubConveyorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.SubConveyorField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

During the runtime a object of this type is created and the propertie **ExtensionDataField** is filled. But how could i access the values of this object?

The structure of the **ExtensionDataObject** is the following during the runtime:
[image]

I tried in the following but i have no chance to access the value **"M6\M6_SC2_1"**:

```
    var props = a.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
       var propertieValue =  prop.GetValue(data.Position.ExtensionData, null);
       var subProps = propertieValue.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
       foreach (var subprop in subProps)
       {
          var subPropertieValue = prop.GetValue(data.Position.ExtensionData, null);
       }
     }
```

Comment: No one could answer the question?